# NServiceBus as service

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to set up my NServiceBus handler after build process as windows service using this approach:

```
NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /serviceName:MyServer.dll 
/displayName:"My Super Duper service" 
/description:"My server installed by NService Magic"
```

service is installed but: 
1. is not started
2. is blocking files in bin, so do I have to copy my files first to other folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. is not started

Yes, you need to start it manually or you could us `sc start MyServer.dll`

> 2. is blocking files in bin, so do I have to copy my files first to other folder

Yes, you need to copy those files to a different folder otherwise the files are locked